Updating attribute table is not working on QGIS
I am really not figuring out, why I can't update this field on the attribute table in the screen. When I run, it is not updating the UN to Steep values.

Any suggestions?

Selecting the field name in the drop down under "update existing field" might help

It looks like you haven't chosen a field under the 'Update Existing Field' tick box? You need to choose the field you want to update and then try to run the query again.


The glitch in the GUI (which incorrectly allow to click on OK / Apply even if no field is selecte) will be fixed since the release of QGIS 3.40.1 https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/59422.
